# Why some Github pull request approval checkmarks have different colors (green, gray)?

Tags: github

We have a PR where one approve checkmark is black while the other is green. The green checkmark shows in the "Changes Approved" area at the bottom of the Conversation tab as approved while the black checkmark does not.  However, both show checked beside the approver's name.

Is there some significance to the colors? And why would one person that approved the PR now show in the "Changes Approved" section?

Comment: `git` doesn't have the concept of a PR. Can you clarify (and add a tag) for what `git` provider you are using? EG Bitbucket, GitHub, GitLab, etc.

Comment: my apologies - we just call it git but it is really github

Comment: @efultz: Calling GitHub "git" is a really good habit to break.

Comment: Fair enough.  But does anyone know the answer to the original question?  Why would github mark the approver with an approval but show only one approver in the Changes Approved section?  The person in question made request for changes which were made.  Conversations were resolved.  Person approved.

Answer (score 13):

This may not be an answer for every instance but we found in this situation the problem was the person had read privileges to the repository which allowed him to review and comment and even approve but when the approval was processed because he did not have collaborator privilege it did not complete the approval.  Once privileges were updated things looked better.

Answer (score 7):

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/approving-a-pull-request-with-required-reviews

> If your repository requires approving reviews from people with write or admin permissions, then any approvals from people with these permissions are denoted with a green check mark, and approvals from people without these permissions have a ***gray check mark***. Approvals with a gray check mark do not affect whether the pull request can be merged.